# Cannot remove a file from Team Drive with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

The following code works fine on Team Drive:

```
var files = folder.getFiles();

while (files.hasNext())
{
  var file = files.next();

  file.setTrashed(true);
//Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());
}
```

The commented out line also works fine in a non-Team Drive folder.

However, running the Drive.Files.remove line on a Team drive gives this error:

**GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.delete failed with error: File not found: (file ID here)**

Is this a permissions issue (with a misleading error)?  Or is there something special I need to do to run Drive.Files.remove on a Team drive?  Searching Stack Overflow yielded nothing tangible.

I checked the file ID and it is valid, and the script is running as me and I am a Manager on the Team Drive folder.  The Drive API is enabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Drive.Files.remove(fileId, {supportsTeamDrives:true});
```

Not sure if this will help but thought it might be worth a try.